# How to use javascript promise value to store it into a variable then use it in another block scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance

so i am building a trading bot with javascript using binance-node-api and stuck upon some block scope. SO i was using the line of code below :

```
let usdtBalance;
async function getUSDTBalance() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    try {
      const futuresBalance = await binance.futuresBalance();
      const usdtBalanceObj = futuresBalance.find(
        (asset) => asset.asset === "USDT"
      );

      if (usdtBalanceObj) {
        usdtBalance = parseFloat(usdtBalanceObj.balance);
        console.log("Your initial USDT balance:", usdtBalance);
      } else {
        console.error("USDT not found!");
        usdtBalance = 0;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in getting USDT balance:", error.message);
      usdtBalance = 0;
    }
    resolve(usdtBalance);
  });
}
(async () => {
  await getUSDTBalance();
  console.log("USDT balance for trade amount:", usdtBalance);
  console.log("Data type for trade amount:", typeof usdtBalance);
})();
```

So i thought declaring usdtBalance at the top store the promise value into the variable, but turns out if i use usdtBalance outside of this code, the value returned undefined. I am planning to use the value of this usdtBalance to another line of code (binance.futuresMarketBuy) but it can't do mathematical operations on object. Did i do somethign wrong? Thanks!

I tried to save it as a variable but still returns undefined outside of this block scope.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: You are not using the value which your Promise resolves with. So instead of just doing `await getUSDTBalance()` do `let myBalance = await getUSDTBalance(); console.log(myBalance);`. Furthermore get rid of that global `usdtBalance` variable and move it inside the scope of your `getUSDTBalance()`